# Format Levels of cut function

Tags: r, format, cut, levels

thanks to your help I was able to write a little program to group a large set of data into groups that will later be displayed at the x-axis and as a frequency of the corresponding group at the y-axis. By accident I forgot to use the labels="" parameter, but the result was good. More or less.

So how can I change the labels of all groups from this format:

(-4.5e+04,-2.25e+04] to this format -45.000 - 22.500? If it is possible, I would be very happy to see those dots, too.

```
               Gruppen Abweichung
1     -45.000 - -22.500         2
2      -22.500 -      0        60
3            0 - 22.500         8
4       22.500 - 45.000         2
```

Down below you can see my the code that brought me to this place.

```
# TEST Value

JACKY <- 4 #How many groups do I need?

MYMIN <- -45000 # Min on x-Axis
MYMAX <- 45000  # Max on x-Axis

MYSCHRTW <- (-MYMIN+MYMAX)%/%JACKY  #Steps of groups
################################################################################
# Create a vector for cutting the data into groups
GRENZEN <- seq(from = MYMIN, by = MYSCHRTW, length.out = JACKY)

# To also get the value of MYMAX into the last group
GRENZEN <- c(GRENZEN, MYMAX+1)
#################################################################################
    #Cut this damn thing
setDT(mydata)[ , Gruppen := cut(mydata$Abweichung,breaks=GRENZEN
               )
]

# Delete all rows that are not in a group
mydata <- mydata[complete.cases(mydata), ]

########################################################################################
# Change order from Abweichung, BW_Gesamt, groups to: groups, Abweichung, BW_Gesamt
mydata <- setcolorder(mydata, c("Gruppen", "Abweichung", "BW_Gesamt"))

########################################################################################
# Shrink it to groups only
mydata <- mydata %>%
  group_by(Gruppen) %>%
  summarise(Abweichung = n())
cat("\nOutput of the grouping:\n")
print(mydata)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
               Gruppen Abweichung
                <fctr>      <int>
1 (-4.5e+04,-2.25e+04]          2
2        (-2.25e+04,0]         60
3         (0,2.25e+04]          8
4   (2.25e+04,4.5e+04]          2
```

Comment: hi `options(scipen=20)` should work

Comment: have you tried `dig.lab` parameter like `cut(..., dig.lab = 5)`?

Comment: `cut(..., dig.lab = 5)`
`mydata$Gruppen <- gsub(',', ' - ', mydata$Gruppen)`
`mydata$Gruppen <- gsub('\\(', '', mydata$Gruppen)`
`mydata$Gruppen <- gsub('\\]', '', mydata$Gruppen)`
Did the trick to format it like this:
`> class(mydata$Gruppen)`
`[1] "character"`
`> print(mydata)`
`Gruppen Abweichung`
`<chr>      <int>`
`1 -45000 - -22500          2`
`2      -22500 - 0         60`
`3       0 - 22500          8`
`4   22500 - 45001          2`
But how can I add point to the thousands?